# Rails: creating a hash inside an initializers file and using it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using one file in the initializers directory to declare constants for use in different parts of the application.

```
FIRST_STR = "First Name"
LAST_STR = "Last Name"
new_user_hash = Hash.new
new_user_hash[ "first" ] = FIRST_STR
new_user_hash[ "last" ] =  LAST_STR
```

I have no problem using `FIRST_STR` and `LAST_STR` in different parts of the application, but when I try to use `new_user_hash`, I get the following error message:

> undefined local variable or method `new_user_hash' for #<#:0x007f8da5752da0>

Is it not possible to define/declare a hash in one file and use it in another?

Comment: Where are you trying to use `new_user_hash`? It can't be accessed outside of that file since it's a local variable.

Answer (score 7):

I think you may be running into scoping—`new_user_hash` is a local and may not be available to the rest of the application.  If you make it a global (by calling it `$new_user_hash`) it will be available.  In the case of `FIRST_STR` and `LAST_STR`, they are constants which are effectively globals.

Update your code to be either:

```
$new_user_hash = { "first" => FIRST_STR, "last" => LAST_STR }
```

or

```
NEW_USER_HASH  = { "first" => FIRST_STR, "last" => LAST_STR }
```

And you will be able to access `$new_user_hash` or `NEW_USER_HASH` from the other parts of your application.

Another strategy is to define a module:

```
module MyAppConfig
  NEW_USER_HASH = { "first" => FIRST_STR, "last" => LAST_STR } 
end
```

Then elsewhere you can access it by prefixing it with the module name:

```
MyAppConfig::NEW_USER_HASH["first"]
```

This is a more accepted approach since it doesn't create more global variables.

Comment: `MyAppConfig` probably makes more sense as a module, since it's not meant to be new-ed and is merely a container for encapsulating constants.

Comment: That is a great point Andrew.  Thanks, I'll update my answer.

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions. I will try some stuff and post what works. Yes, it's a scoping issue. When I moved the Hash declaration to the file I was using it in, it worked fine.

Comment: Is the module approach to help avoid a name conflict only, or are there other advantages to using the module approach?

Comment: Andrew's suggestion is a good one: since there is no implementation (i.e. no state) there is no need to make it a class -- you'd never instantiate it (call new) and it really has no behavior of its own, it's just there to namespace the data.  Does this make sense?

Answer (score 0):

You should use a config management gem: https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/Configuration_Management